# Soft question - Memory address of the last byte allocated of an array

Tags: variables, hex, memory-address

The variable `int A[10]` is allocated from the HEX address `DDDD04BA`. I would like to find the HEX address of the last byte allocated of the array. Why we subtract 1 from:
`DDDD04BA+28=DDDD04E2`, `DDDD04E2-1=DDDD04E1`? Also, why the HEX address of the first byte of `A[8]` is `DDDD.04BA+32=DDDD04DA`, shouldn't it be `+36` instead since it starts from `A[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Address of first element of array is `&A[0]=DDDD04BA`
Address of element A[1] is obtained by adding 4 to this value
Address of element A[i] is &A[0]+4*i
And the last element A[9] is at address &A[0]+4*9=&A[0]+36=&A[0]+0x24

A[9] is formed of 4 bytes. First is at address &A[9] and last at address &A[9]+3
We get the result 0xDDDD04BA+0x24+3=DDDD04E1

For the same reason, &A[8]=&A[0]+8*4=0xDDDD04DA

Do not forget that arrays with a 0 index, so to find address of element i, you just have to add i*sizeof(array_element) to base address.